# Getting run-time error 9: Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

My abilities with VBA are very limited to copying someone else's hard work and tinker with it to make it do what I need.
I have been looking over different sites and playing with a number of options. I need to search a network folder - match all the files in the folder to the file number stored in column A and create a hyperlink to those files and maintain the file name in column A.
I can' quite find what I need and haven't been able to blend those online to create my answer.
The spread sheet is added to weekly with new data added to the existing, so the number of file names in column A is variable.

Would it be possible for any file type/extension searched for to be a variable also or must the file type be a of one type eg. msg or pdf?

The following code is just one unsuccessful effort

```
Sub Hyperlinks()
'
    Const sFILENAME_CELLS   As String = "A2:A3200"

    Const sLINKS_COLUMN     As String = "A"
    Const sFOLDER_NAME      As String = "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Benny PDFs"
    Const sSHEET_NAME       As String = "Projects"

    Dim rFilenameCells      As Range
    Dim rFilenameCell       As Range
    Dim sFilename           As String
    Dim sFullName           As String
    Dim wksTarget           As Worksheet
    Dim iRowNo              As Integer

    Set wksTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sSHEET_NAME)

    Set rFilenameCells = wksTarget.Range(sFILENAME_CELLS)

    For Each rFilenameCell In rFilenameCells.Cells

        sFilename = rFilenameCell.value

        If sFilename <> vbNullString Then

            sFullName = sFOLDER_NAME & "\" & sFilename

'           Check that the file exists in the specified folder
            If Dir$(sFullName) = sFilename Then

                iRowNo = rFilenameCell.row

                With wksTarget
                    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range(sLINKS_COLUMN & iRowNo), _
                                    Address:=sFullName, _
                                    TextToDisplay:=sFilename
                End With

            End If

        End If

    Next rFilenameCell

End Sub
```

Comment: in which line do you get error 9?

Comment: Probably you do not have `Projects` sheet in your workbook.

Answer (score 0):

> Getting run-time error 9: Subscript out of range

The reason is probably you do not have `Projects` sheet in your workbook.
Also change this line:

```
Const sLINKS_COLUMN     As String = "A"
```

to something else then A, because like this the filename in `A2:A3200` will be replaced with hyperlink to the file.